# Can one prove Rademacher’s theorem via the rising sun lemma?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, harmonic-analysis

The classical Rademacher’s theorem states that Lipschitz continuous functions on $\mathbb R^n$ are differentiable almost everywhere.

In dimension one, a stronger result holds - it can be shown that functions of bounded variation are almost everywhere differentiable. Most commonly this is done via the so called *[rising sun lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rising_sun_lemma)* which roughly speaking provides quantitative bounds on the measure of the sets of non differentiability.

In higher dimensions, the result for functions of bounded variation is no longer true, however I wonder if a suitable generalisation of the rising sun lemma would be able to prove the Rademacher’s theorem in higher dimensions.

In dimension 1, one shines the sun from the left and from the right, and brings it to a nadir and zenith. In higher dimensions, say 2, I have in mind to shine it from all possible directions in $S^1$, also raising and lowering the sun as needed, as in the proof in dimension 1.

For clarity, here is the question statement:

> **Question:** Can a suitable generalisation of the rising sun lemma be used to prove Rademacher’s theorem on almost everywhere differentiability of Lipschitz functions on $\mathbb R^n$?